# Birth of Sri Vaishnavism

Tags: vishnu, history, sri-vaishnava, vishishtadvaita

I want to know when Sri Vaishnavism came into existence, and whether it was before the bhakti  movement or after.

Comment: It was before the Bhakti movement (which came along with Chaitanya Mahaprabhu). Sri Vaishnavism is partly advaitic, meaning it incorporates both bhakti and gyan marga.